# Efficient way of reducing a Dataframe from wide to long based on the logic mentioned

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame with col names 'a', 'b', 'c'

```
#Input
import pandas as pd

list_of_dicts = [
  {'a' : 0, 'b' : 4, 'c' : 3},
  {'a' : 1, 'b' : 1, 'c' : 2  },
  {'a' : 0, 'b' : 0, 'c' : 0  },
  {'a' : 1, 'b' : 0, 'c' : 3  },
  {'a' : 2, 'b' : 1, 'c' : 0  }
]

df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dicts)
```

```
#Input DataFrame
-----|------|------|-----|
     |  a   |  b   |  c  |   
-----|------|------|-----|
 0   |  0   |  4   |  3  |       
 1   |  1   |  1   |  2  |      
 2   |  0   |  0   |  0  |      
 3   |  1   |  0   |  3  |      
 4   |  2   |  1   |  0  |
```

I want to reduce the wide DataFrame to One column, with the column names
as DataFrame values multiplied by the corresponding row values. The operation must be done Row wise.

```
#Output
    |  Values |
-----------------  
 0  |    b    |
 1  |    b    |
 2  |    b    |
 3  |    b    |
 4  |    c    |
 5  |    c    |
 6  |    c    |
 7  |    a    |
 8  |    b    |
 9  |    c    |
 10 |    c    |
 11 |    a    |
 12 |    c    |
 13 |    c    |
 14 |    c    |
 15 |    a    |
 17 |    a    |
 18 |    b    |
```

Explanation:
Row 0 in the Input DataFrame has 4 'b' and 3 'c', so the first seven elements of the output DataFrame are bbbbccc

Row 1 similarly has 1 'a' 1 'b' and 2 'c', so the output will have abcc as the next 4 elements

Row 2 has 0's across, so would be skipped entirely.

**The Order of the output is very important**
For example, the first row has '4' b and 3 'c', so the output DataFrame must be bbbbccc because Column 'b' comes before column 'c'. The operation must be row-wise from left to right.

I'm trying to find an **efficient** way in order to accomplish this. The *real dataset is too big* for me to compute. Please provide the python3 solution.

Comment: Is that what you really want?  Does the fact that [{'a':0,'b':4,'c':3}] and [{'a':0,'b':4,'c':2},{'a':0,'b':0,'c':1}] yield the same output not cause a problem?

Comment: What matter is the order of the output. For example, the first row as 4 'b' and 3 'c', then the output dataframe must have the first 7 rows as bbbbccc. The output cannot be bcbcbcb or any other combination.

Comment: But from how I understand from your description, my two examples would have exactly the same output: bbbbccc.  Just checking that this is what you expect

Comment: Oh, i get your question. Nope that does not cause an issue. I'm sorry I didn't understand your problem earlier. The two should give the same output.

Comment: As for the complexity you are just walking the dataset so the process is O(N), no?  The efficiency question is how to get the maximal processing happening in C code rather than a Python loop, right?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't phrase it better. I'm not sure if this can be done in O(N) since you would have to iterate over the dataframe row-wise. If there is a combination of using List comprehensions or apply or map, then that would be sufficient. Primarily I'm trying to get the output as quickly as possible. I want to achieve this in python3 even if there is a tradeoff in time between C and python. I'm using two for loops and iterating over element in the dataframe which is too inefficient (O(N*N)) .

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but it would seem to be O(N*M) where in your example M=3, not M=N.  The advantage of things like List comprehensions is that the single python statement happens in the C loop rather than a Python loop, which is what I meant.

Comment: I would have to think about it for a while to see if there was any way of using the pandas reshaping code (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/reshaping.html) to do what you want, but I would wonder where your data is coming from and whether it would be easier to stream through the input data rather that loading everything into memory not the way you want it in the first place.

Comment: I'm reading the input from a flat file... Since I'm new to Python and big data in general, it's very hard for me to process the data on my memory. Essentially I'm using pd.read_csv() to read in the data. If any solution that can reduce the time, whether it be file streaming or efficient code would greatly be appreciated. Please don't worry about time complexity for the time being.

Comment: Sorry, I had to step away.  Last question, do you need the resulting file entirely in memory at the end, or can you just write the output of each record as you go?

Comment: Very true. For the purpose of my analysis, I think the code above would suffice. But I take your point take loading large data in the memory doesn't make sense and probably using a DictReader or using Dask DataFrames and partitioning the results would make more sense. The output file is around 2 million records, so my memory can sustain it. That is a bad idea though. Thank you for the solution that you provided! I'll certainly try to incorporate that into the code. Thank you so much for the patience and perceiverance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) the data (you could [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) as well), and drop rows where the count is zero. Finally use [numpy.repeat](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html#numpy.repeat) to build a new array, and build your new dataframe from that.

```
reshape = df.stack().droplevel(0).loc[lambda x: x != 0]
pd.DataFrame(np.repeat(reshape.index, reshape), columns=['values'])

 values
0   b
1   b
2   b
3   b
4   c
5   c
6   c
7   a
8   b
9   c
10  c
11  a
12  c
13  c
14  c
15  a
16  a
17  b
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This accomplishes the task!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think pandas buys you anything in this process, and especially if you have a large amount of data you don't want to read that all into memory and reprocess it into another large data structure.

```
import csv
with open('input.csv', 'r') as fh:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fh)
    for row in reader:
        for key in reader.headers:
            value = int(row[key])
            for i in range(value):
                print(key)
```